# Keyboard not show onload

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, keyboard

I want the keyboad show automatically onload, but it did not work as i expect
here is the code i use:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [seachBar2 setDelegate:self];

}

- (BOOL)Searchbar2ShouldReturn:(UISearchBar *)searchBar2 {

    [searchBar2 becomeFirstResponder];

    return YES;

}
```

Coud somebody will point me how to fix this
thank you somuch

Comment: Looks like iPhone development in Obj-C

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [seachBar2 setDelegate:self];
    [seachBar2 becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: No it still not work, it not show onload. :(
I don´t know what language is that, i´m new with this.
hmm

Comment: You might want to try overriding viewDidAppear instead (but I'm just guessing).

Comment: hmm How ? 
I got headach with this whole night..
trying to look at google but no solution.
so sad :(

Comment: yes I have tried overriding viewDidAppear instead of viewDidLoad
but still not work...the keyboard not slide and show at once, until I have to click on search bar then it show,,,
hmmmm so stressss:(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `searchBar2` in your code points `(IBOutlet)` to the `searchBar` in the Interaface Builder.

in your code:

```
IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar2;
```

In IB:
goto the search bar's Connections Inspector (apple-2) and drag the `Referencing Outlet` to `File Owner` and select `searchBar2`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, 5 have checked everything is done, but I don´t have any idea,
why it would not slide and display onload....hmmmm
should i have some special lines of code ?

Answer (score 0):

You do need to override `viewDidAppear:`, and verify it's actually being called (put a breakpoint or an `NSLog()` statement in there). You should also determine the language you're coding in (it's `Objective C`).

Your `-Searchbar2ShouldReturn:` method will never be called by the system. I think you may need to go back and work through a few of Apple's tutorials here; your grasp of the frameworks seems tenuous, at best.

Comment: oww!! Sound so complicate, I will try the best:)
but thanks for comment and help...I really hope i will find solution.
I guess i lake some lines of code.....hmmm

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this, and it helped but the answers are vague.
All you need to do now in iOS 5 is make an outlet connection to your object (for example a UITextField) and then in viewDidLoad method type;

```
[myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

or for your search bar

```
[searchBar2 becomeFirstResponder];
```